# ITask Fails To Load during .Net Core Project Build Process

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild-task

I have a fairly simple class the inherits from `ITask`, and runs as a build task for updating versions (`VersionUpdater.dll`). The project file entry is as follows:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="VersionUpdater" AssemblyFile="VersionUpdater.dll" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <VersionUpdater />
</Target>
```

This perfectly fine for regular .Net projects; however I tried to load it in .Net Core project build tasks and got this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB4062 The "VersionUpdater" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly C:...\VersionUpdater.dll. Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:...\VersionUpdater.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
>   declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
>   available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Ok, so I figure perhaps the DLL has to be built using .Net Core now, so I did, and created `VersionUpdater.Core.dll` (`AssemblyFile="VersionUpdater.Core.dll"`), and got this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB4062 The "VersionUpdater" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly C:...\VersionUpdater.Core.dll. Could not load file or
>   assembly '**System.Runtime**, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
>   declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
>   available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

As I said, the code works for normal .Net projects.  It just doesn't want to work with .Net Core projects.  Anything I'm missing?  Is it a bug that System.Runtime is not found for .Net Core?

*(source is here: https://github.com/rjamesnw/VersionUpdater)*

Answer (score 2):

To make a task work with both 'dotnet msbuild' and MSBuild.exe, you need to cross compile the task for .NET Framework and a .NET Core-compatible framework such as .NET Standard. Then, you need to vary which task assembly loads based and the runtime type of MSBuild. You can detect this using MSBuildRuntimeType. For example,

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TaskAssembly Condition=" '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core'">.\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\MyTaskAssembly.dll</TaskAssembly>
    <TaskAssembly Condition=" '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' != 'Core'">.\bin\Debug\net46\MyTaskAssembly.dll</TaskAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="MyTaskName" AssemblyFile="$(TaskAssembly)" />
```

See this blog post for a detailed explanation and sample. http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/07/05/msbuild-task-in-nuget/